# Why does a memmap need a filename when I try to reshape a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pickle

I am getting a stacktrace that I find difficult to understand:

```
screwed_up_code.py in atleast_4d(arr)
     28 def atleast_4d(arr):
     29     stshape = arr.shape
     30     while len(stshape)<4: stshape+=(1,)
     31     print arr.shape, stshape
---> 32     return arr.reshape(stshape)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/memmap.pyc in __array_finalize__(self, obj)
    255         if hasattr(obj, '_mmap'):
    256             self._mmap = obj._mmap
--> 257             self.filename = obj.filename
    258             self.offset = obj.offset
    259             self.mode = obj.mode

AttributeError: 'memmap' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

In case you wonder `arr.shape = (192, 384, 6)` and `stshape = (192, 384, 6, 1)`

---

**UPDATE**

As suggested by NPE , I looked into [the bug report of a similar sounding AttributeError](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1809). A poster there blamed it on attributes getting lost due to pickling of ndarrays. I am indeed pickling arrays and when re-vitalize the loaded arrays like so:

```
newarr = numpy.ndarray(pickled_array)
pickled_array = newarr                  # use the recreated instead of the pickled arr
```

I get warnings instead of Exceptions and my code runs:

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tell'",) in  ignored
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tell'",) in  ignored
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tell'",) in <bound method memmap.__del__ of memmap([  85389.2734375,  125935.75     ,  173624.09375  ,  272958.78125  ,
        305687.65625  ,  433026.3125   ], dtype=float32)> ignored
```

I am happy enough that my code runs and will leave it at that for the moment.

Comment: It would really help us to help you if you included an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I know - I wish I could. The problem with all the SSCCE's that I am trying is that they actually work and don't produce this problem. You can see that ```atleast_4d``` is a very benign little function. I am handing in a numpy array of shape (192, 384, 6). When I give it a newly created array of the same size, it doesn't happen. Somehow, my code prepares the array in a way such that it blows up inside ```atleast_4d```.

Comment: Sounds like this is probably fixed in current numpy. (though that is probably 1.7.x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds very similar to [this bug](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1809).

The [stack trace](https://gist.github.com/tfmoraes/944144) there is a bit different, but the code ends up failing at exactly the same point with exactly the same exception:

```
 File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\memmap.py", line 257, in __array_finalize__
   self.filename = obj.filename
AttributeError: 'memmap' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

The [`numpy-discussion` thread](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2011-April/056043.html) where this was first reported suggests that the issue might be related to [this other ticket](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1452) having to do with pickling of `memmap` objects. In any event, the thread is worth a read.

Comment: you might be on to something. There is some pickling involved in the creation of this ```ndarray```. Thank you - will investigate and come back.

Comment: @DrSAR: Sure. Have a read of the discussion thread I've just linked to.

Comment: Yes I have which is what made me believe you were right. I have since edited the question showing data to confirm your findings. Thanks a lot.